# calculate percentages in single select

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to calculate, Of the users that have created a reservation at a SitDownRestaurant, what is the percentage
that the user has recommended that SitDownRestaurant?

I tried this, but I don't understand how to find percentages from it:

```sql
select reservations.UserName 
from reservations, sitdownrestaurant 
where reservations.RestaurantId = sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId 
and reservations.UserName in (
  select recommendations.UserName 
  from recommendations, sitdownrestaurant 
  where recommendations.RestaurantId = sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId
);
```

Comment: Have a read about joins

Answer (score 0):

OK, so we take the inner join between `sitdownrestaurant` and `reservations`.

We do a left outer join with recommendations.
If we did an inner join with recommendations we want every user with both a reservation and a recommendation.  However, since we want records for all the reservations, even those without recommendations, we use an outer join instead.

Then we group by the restaurant.
If we do a `count(recommendations.RestaurantId)` this will count all the non-null values in the group.
Since the outer join will use NULL when there was no matching record, this will be the number of recommendations.

However, a `count(sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId)` will be a count of all the records.

So the percent will be the number of recommendations divided by the total number of records for the restaurant.  (You might multiply this by 100 to get the percentage.)

```
select count(recommendations.RestaurantId)/count(sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId)
from sitdownrestaurant
  inner join reservations
    on reservations.RestaurantId = sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId
  left outer join recommendations
    on recommendations.RestaurantId = sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId
    and recommendations.UserName = reservations.UserName
group by sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId
```

Comment: okay. but I'm getting 1.000 as output. is it something related to this statement ?select count(recommendations.RestaurantId)/count(sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId)

Comment: Check if there are in fact any reservations which do not have recommendations.

Also check `select recommendations.RestaurantId/sitdownrestaurant.RestaurantId` without the `group by`.  (Use `order by` instead.)